# Conditional loading with Sql*Loader

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, substr, sql-loader

Using SQL*Loader, I want a condition like this:

**Load the record if : `substr(Col,3,2)='06'`**

> ```
>       Col
>     ------
>    10062034
>       .
>       .
>       .
> ```

Is there any way to combine WHEN with substr (or any other function) in control file?

I tried `WHEN (substr(Col,3,2)='06')` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the syntax for the `WHEN` clause is quite restrictive; see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657. You can only restrict based on either an entire field, or else on specific character positions. That said, if you're using a fixed format, then you can express `substr(Col,3,2)` as a range of character positions, and that will work. For example, if `Col` starts at character #20, then you can use `WHEN (22:23) = '06'`. But if you're using a free format, like `FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`, then you won't generally know the character-offset of `Col`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine When with other function, as your code:

```
CASE substr(col,3,2)

WHEN '06' THEN
-- Do st
ELSE
-- Do st
END
```

HTH.